# Using dropdownlistfor for model with list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

How do I use dropdownlistfor for this viewmodel?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Model1> model1{ get; set; }
}

    public class Model1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id{ get; set; }
}
```

How should I do this?

```
@model Models.ViewModels.ViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.model1)
```

Comment: You cant bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. What exactly are you trying to do? - do you want to display multiple dropdowns or one dropdown?

Comment: I have multiple dropdowns on the same view, but with each dropdown has its list of objects

Comment: So what property do you want to bind to. So far all you have shown is a collection of `Model1`. A dropdownlist is for binding the selected option to a property of a model. You need a property to bind to and a collection representing the options. For example you might have `class Product` with property `int Category` and then you have a collection of categories that you use to select the products category and bind to property `Category`

Comment: I would like to bind it to ViewModel.model1.Id

Comment: But it is already a `model1` - you can bind it to itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the selected id into your viewmodel.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Model1Items{ get; set; }
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
public class Model1{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In the Controller:

```
var items = (from m in db.Model1s
             select new SelectListItem{
                 Value = m.Id,
                 Text = m.Name
             }); // This is where you bind your Model1 to the dropdownlist

// Add a default id-name pair as needed.
YourViewModel.Model1Items = new SelectList(items.ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, Model.Model1Items)
```

Comment: What should the SelectedId represent, is it just a dummy id ?...I would like the the dropdownlist to show Model1.Name, and hold value of Model1.Id

Comment: The SelectedId holds the value of the selected Model1.id.  I edited the post. In you controller, you would return the Model1s as a SelectList();

Comment: But how can I then get the ID from Model1 when making a HTTPPOST? The selecedId is only one id, but I need it to be a list of IDs, Model1.Id..

Comment: The dropdownlist would show all ids and names because the Model1s is a list of `SelectListItem`. What do you want to accomplish with the POST?  If you need a ajax call, you should be able to fetch the id with js and POST that id.

Comment: With the post, I would like to get the ID of Model1 that is selected

Comment: I renamed it to `Model1Items`. Hope this makes more sense.